# How to bind after user selected row only on ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid for dynamic data loading. I can able to get console result from user row selection option. initially ui-grid has been loaded with data, after user row selection, loaded with selected row only. Please tell me how do i implement this feature. I got row selection result by following code using;

```
columnDefs:  columnNames.map(colName => {
        return {
          name: colName,
          type: DefaultTableColumnType,
          cellTemplate: `
            <div ng-click="grid.appScope.clickHandler(row)" ng-if="!grid.getCellValue(row, col).startsWith('%html')"
                 class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
              {{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}
            </div>
            <div  ng-click="grid.appScope.clickHandler(row)" ng-if="grid.getCellValue(row, col).startsWith('%html')"
                 ng-bind-html="grid.getCellValue(row, col).split('%html')[1]"
                 class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
            </div>
          `,
        }
      }),
    appScopeProvider: {
                    clickHandler: function onCellClick(row) {
    console.log("Entered");
        console.log(row.entity);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to change the data that populate the table with a new array with only that element.

If you use $scope.data = [...];

then should be:

```
appScopeProvider: {
      clickHandler: function onCellClick(row) {
        console.log(row.entity);
        $scope.data = [row.entity];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this.

Comment: $scope.data is in controller file, The above java script in separate file soi'm processing in another way of getting data.